web whatsapp sending message from socket
I ask this question because I didn't know how to ask question on this post : Web WhatsApp Web Socket Post Message
 exampleSocket.send(new Blob(["your message datas"]));

I've tried this code to sending message, I got error message : "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE",
also there is no any effects, when I trying using JSON stringify, like this :
var datas = {to:'61xxxxxxx@c.us',from:'61zzzzzzzzz@c.us',type:"text",text:{body:"xxxxxxx"}};
var data = {data: new Blob([datas])};
data = JSON.stringify(data);
exampleSocket.send(data);

Could anyone give me some sample data maybe json or etc before the data convert into blob?
Thanks

Do you know how Whatsapp protocol works? It uses XMPP over TCP/TLS. I don't think it uses websockets. And even if it is a lot more complicated than just sending such simple JSONs around. For example you need to authenticate. There's a lot to learn about it. I suggest you start googling "Whatsapp protocol". It would be better to find and use some library instead.
